# How can visible buttonlink in Gridview if rows no have data Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have problems for invisible linksbutton in gridview, if rows no have the data.

[This the result from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFKSc.jpg)

my Html code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        Width="700px" AllowPaging="True" 
        onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" DataKeyNames="ProductId" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
     <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField Text="view" CommandName="Select">
                <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
            </asp:ButtonField>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ProductId" DataField="ProductId" >
                 <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ProductName" DataField="ProductName">
                <ItemStyle Width="300px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="QuantityPerUnit" DataField="QuantityPerUnit">
                <ItemStyle Width="200px"></ItemStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
   </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

My Aspx Code:

```
    public void BindData()
    {
        string strConnection = @"Data Source=.\sa;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ProductId, ProductName, SupplierId from Products", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        //Script row 10
        int rowcount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        int remainingCount = 10 - (rowcount % 10);
        for (int i = 0; i < remainingCount; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();  
    }
```

anybody can improve my code, please..

Comment: Did you check how many rows you are getting in `ds.Tables[0]` ? What is the purpose of `int remainingCount = 10 - (rowcount % 10);` and adding empty rows in the table? If you insert empty rows in the table then it will be displayed as empty in the GridView....

Comment: Why you are adding unnecessary rows?

Answer (score -1):

if I understand the problem correctly, you can solve it via rowdatabound.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound?view=netframework-4.8